# Cannot use custom ListView layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I am trying to create a custom `ListView` but i can not even compile it, since it gives me this error early on:

```
Error:(25, 63) error: cannot find symbol variable listing
```

where "listing" is the xml file name for my `ListView` layout.

What am i doing wrong?
This is my fragment code:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListingFragment extends Fragment {

    private CustomcursorAdapter mCustomcursorAdapter;
    private ListView mListView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listing, container, false);

        //CursorAdapter
        mCustomcursorAdapter = new CustomcursorAdapter(view.getContext(), null, 0);

        //ListView
        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listing);
        mListView.setAdapter(mCustomcursorAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

fragment_listing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity and activity_main

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            Listing listing = new Listing();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, listing).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your fragment_listing.xml

Comment: @Ultimo_m fragment layout posted

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment_listing.xml you should add:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >
      </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It didnt compile because you didnt have that id in R.java

**Edit**

In your activty_main xml add:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Then in your MainActivity add:

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = new Listing();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

Comment: What should be the display?

Comment: Now it can compile just fine, but i am getting my activity_main layout to display!

Comment: This displays your fragment layout, do you want to display that ?

Comment: This is displaying my activity_main layout!

Comment: Look fragment_listing is your fragment xml, what is your activity layout ?

Comment: I am getting that Hello World to display!

Comment: Sorry but I didnt understand you. You want to display hello world or your fragment ?

Comment: I want do display my fragment but i am getting Hello World!

Comment: It compiles and runs without a problem, but it does not display a ListView!